# VS Database project Error with %%physloc%%

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am receiving the following error from a SQL Server(2014) database project on VS2012: **Error  SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near %.**

And this is the code giving the error:

```sql
SELECT distinct sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter(C.%%physloc%%) as id
FROM T_Customer C
```

The query runs just fine in SQL Server, but I want to get rid of the error in VS to be able to compile the whole project.

Comment: I would suggest not using that function in the first place. It is undocumented. And why do you need this functionality in an application?

Comment: It is part of an existing database. It was not my decision to use it, I just have create the project in TFS to start working with version control.

Comment: Of course it is part of the database. It is an undocumented procedure in all sql server databases. It is really bizarre to have this in a program. And using undocumented behavior is very risky that should not be used in production code. Not sure why you would be getting that error in VS though.

Comment: What I meant is that I am not using it, the use of the function is already in a stored procedure that somebody else created years ago, the SP has been working in production for years, I am updating the Source control only. I just want to get rid of the error :/

Answer (score 0):

This is a risk you take when you use undocumented syntax.

The SSDT parser will be expecting an identifier there. The column name isn't quoted it so the grammar demands that it should meet the [rules for regular identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers#rules-for-regular-identifiers) or be one of a few **documented** exceptions (e.g. `$identity`, `$rowguid`)

You won't be able to build the project unless you change the stored proc to not use that syntax or hide it from the parser (e.g. inside an `EXEC`).

I recommend rewriting to not use the syntax. It is extremely unlikely that the approach shown in the question is going to be a good solution to anything. Chances are that it won't work as desired in the face of concurrent writes causing row movement.